# How can I update this element from the viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I'm using Material Design toolkit and I want to somehow set the DrawerHost to open or closed from the view model with a property.  I have a property in the view model that is already updated from another source.  I just need to translate that property to the xaml.  Any help appreciated.

```
<UserControl x:Class="GS.Server.Focuser.FocuserView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<materialDesign:DrawerHost  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="2" 
        IsLeftDrawerOpen="{Binding ElementName=MenuToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}" 
        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}">
    <materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent>
        <Grid Width="700">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                <ToggleButton DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" 
                    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignHamburgerToggleButton}" 
                    Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DrawerHost.CloseDrawerCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{x:Static Dock.Left}"
                    IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MenuToggleButton, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Focuser Settings Go Here</Label>
        </Grid>
    </materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent>
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DrawerHost.OpenDrawerCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{x:Static Dock.Left}"
            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignHamburgerToggleButton}" IsChecked="False"
                          x:Name="MenuToggleButton"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="This is the Focuser Page" 
                       FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</materialDesign:DrawerHost>
```

Comment: yup, just cant figure out how to add it in this loop, but i'll work on it

Comment: Just figured that out, changing the first IsLeftDrawerOpen binding seems to work.

Comment: can you explain in an example using OpenSetupDialog as the new property binding?

Comment: That's the new bool property that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged. I need to tie that into ischecked somehow.